# Can I add values to a MySQL table via a form based on a match between values in a textbox and values in a column in the table?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, match

I have a MySQL table with a number of columns, including one called 'Name'.

I would like to design a form for a webpage which consists of two textboxes, A and B. In textbox A the user would be required to enter their name, and in textbox B some other information.

I would like the PHP script to check if the Name in Textbox A matches a value already in the Name column in the MySQL table, and if it does, add the value in Textbox B to another column in this table.  If the name is not found, I would like the script to return an error, along the lines of "Your booking was not found on our database".

Is it possible to do this using PHP/MySQL and if it is, how would I go about this?

**CURRENT CODE**

```
$row_count = count($_POST['name']);

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

if ($row_count > 0) {

$values = array();

 for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
     // variable sanitation...
     $name = mysql_real_escape_string(ucwords($_POST['name'][$i]));
     $workshop = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['workshop'][$i]);

     $query = "SELECT * FROM conference WHERE Name = '$name' ";
     $result = mysql_query($query);

     if ($result) {
     $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);

     if ($rowcount == 0) {echo "no bookings found"; }
     else {
     $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
     $sql = "UPDATE conference SET Workshop = '$workshop' WHERE Name = '$name'";
     mysql_query($sql);
     }

     }
}

}
```

Comment: is this a please write my code for me question??

Comment: a) Yes, it's possible b) You write some code.

Comment: @Laurence Burke Thanks, and, no, it's not a can you write some code for me question.  I googled terms relating to this and didn't come up with anything, hence the question.  I'm glad to hear that it is possible to do this.  I will redouble my efforts to work out the necessary code.  If anyone has any code to help me on my way, or useful links, that would of course be helpful!

Comment: sorry but this question is pretty straight forward form with database verifying question. In other words it just seems like a pretty simple question to be asking without any shown attempts trying to make it work...

Comment: @Laurence Burke Laurence, I have added the code that I now have in place at the end of my original question.  It seems to work, but perhaps is not as good as it could be?  Perhaps you could take a look any suggest improvements?  Also, what would the simplest method of generating an error if the name is not found, on the form page itself, instead of the echo on a blank page? Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
//Get the value from the textbox
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
//Select all rows with the name
$query = "SELECT other_info FROM table1 WHERE name = '$name' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
  $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
  //No rows found
  if ($rowcount == 0) {echo "no bookings found"; }
  else {
    //process the data.
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $other_info = $row['other_info'];
    echo "other_info = ".hmtlentities($other_info);
```

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

**Comments on the code**

```
$row_count = count($_POST['name']);
if ($row_count > 0) {

  mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
  //$values = array(); 
  $name = array();
  $workshop = array()
  $replace = array()

  for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
    // variable sanitation...
    $name[i] = mysql_real_escape_string(ucwords($_POST['name'][$i]));
    $workshop[i] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['workshop'][$i]);
    //if you use option 2
    $replace[i] = "('".$name[i]."','".$workshop[i]."')";
  }
  $names = "'".implode("','",$name)."'";
  $query = "SELECT 1 FROM conference WHERE Name IN $names "; 
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  if ($result) {
    $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($rowcount == 0) {
      echo "<HTMLCODE HERE>"."no bookings found"."<MORE HTML>"; 
    //OPTION 1
    } else {
      for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
        //$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);  
        $sql = "UPDATE conference SET Workshop = '$workshop[i]' 
                WHERE Name LIKE '$name[i]'";
        mysql_query($sql);
      }
    }
    //OPTION2
    } else {
      $replacement = implode(",",$replace);
      $sql = "REPLACE INTO conference (names, workshop) VALUES $replacement "
      mysql_query($sql);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly helped to get me on my way.  I have added the code that I currently have in place, which seems to process the form OK, and add the information from the 'workshop' item to the correct rows in my database.  Would you be able to take a look at it and let me know if you see any glaring errors!  Also, I am wondering how to turn the echo "no bookings found" into an error message that shows on the form itself, instead of an echo on a blank page, so if you have any suggestions about that I'd be glad to hear them. Nick

Comment: Thanks again Johan.  I don't need to replace the names in my table, just add the workshop values where a match with the values in the name column is made.  So I took out option 2 and tried to get it working with option 1, which I haven't been able to do.  I am wondering about the `$names = "'".implode("','",$name)."'";` line as `$names` isn't referred to again.  I am also wondering about the `$query = "SELECT 1 FROM conference WHERE Name IN $name ";` line.  What does the 1 refer to?

Comment: @nick the 1 returns 1 if something is found and nothing if not that way the db does not actually have fetch any data from the db, saving time

Comment: There were brackets missing from the implode line, which prevented your script from working.  Now it looks like this: `$names = "('".implode("','",$name)."')";`  For some reason, with `$name[i]` only the last name on the form is getting added to `$names`.  When I use `$name[]` the correct string is added to `$names`, but then no data is added to the workshop column.  Could you help with this?  Thanks, Nick

Comment: `$name[$i]` and `$workshop[$i]` solved the issue in my last comment.  Perhaps you want to update your answer to reflect these two changes? Thanks for your help, Nick